# Is it possible to use UILocalNotification without displaying a message?

Tags: iphone, ios, uilocalnotification

Can they trigger a method call in my app after some time without interrupting the user?

Comment: if the application is in the background mode that time or the application is in active mode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a local notification without setting its alert text to update your application’s badge number or to play a sound. A notification cannot bring your app out of the background without user interaction, though, so no, you can’t schedule method calls that way.